# How to create a docker image for kafka topic?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to set up docker image for kafka topic. This is what I have in my docker-compose.yml file

```
   version: '2'

   services:

       kafka:

         build:

           context: .

           dockerfile: etc/docker/sqlserver/kafka/Dockerfile

        hostname: kafka-broker `
```

In side my Dockerfile , I have added the below lines to create image and the command to create the topic.

```
    FROM landoop/fast-data-dev:2.3.1

    RUN docker exec -it kafka_broker kafka-topics --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 -- 
    replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic itemlocation
```

But when I see running docker-compose ps , there no container created. Please let me know If I am doing anything wrong. I am novice to docker and kafka.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "environment" in "wurstmeister/kafka" image for create topic:

```
 version: '3' 
 services:   
  kafka:
     image: wurstmeister/kafka
     ports:
       - "9092"
     hostname: kafka-broker
     environment:
       KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "itemlocation:1:1" # topic:partition:replicas
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    environment:
       KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
       KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
       KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "itemlocation:1:1"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

Comment: I use version 2 and when used the above code with version 2,  It pulls the image but the does not create any container.
docker ps gives no result.

Comment: @swetha
use this docker-compose.yml

`version: '2'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'docker.io/zookeeper:3.6.1'
    container_name: zookeeper

  kafka:
    image: 'docker.io/wurstmeister/kafka'
    container_name: kafka
    environment:
            KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
            KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
            KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "itemlocation:1:1"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper`